# How to get background image cover with 100% height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using an image with a height of 5000px, and i want make it always appear 100% in width and height to cover the background, in mobile and desktop.

```
.main {
  position: relative;
  background: url('../images/background.png') no-repeat top center; 
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This code does not work, it makes her not to appear. I always need to set a height, and the problem is that the mobile's height is different from the desktop.

So you could say.. 'you can set height: 100%'.. and I did .. but nothing happens, the image doesn't appear, only if i set with pxs.

Comment: Can you setup a working example in http://jsfiddle.net. We need to see how your HTML and CSS is structured in order to help.

Comment: The only css that i have is that, but yes, i can. I can't show the real image because is from my work, but i can make a copy in size.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqbVvM

Comment: It works , check my answer and the fiddle..

Comment: Use the "new" unit `vh` (viewport height), see also my answer and codepen example below.

Comment: but this will make the image appears 100% in the window, not 100% of the image.. i want make the image appears 100%.

Comment: Ok, that last comment makes me doubt I understood your question right: Do you want the background to cover the viewport or do you want the background to be always the exact size of the original image (640x5892)?

Comment: I just updated my answer below, I hope I guessed correctly what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe it would help if the question would be asked more clearly next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## UPDATE

I feel urged to update my answer since I apparently understood the question the wrong way. I'll leave the old version at the bottom since apparently a lot of people found it helpful even though it failed to answer the original question.

Since your background image is repeating itself, I'll assume you don't want the whole image, just whatever height you need. So, you need 2 things:

1. set a height on `.main`
2. get rid of `background-size` altogether

So, this should actually work for you:

```
.main {
  position: relative;
  background: url('../images/background.png') no-repeat top center; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

If my assumption is correct, there's 1 more thing: you don't need a background over 5000px high to achieve your goal, just reduce it to 1px height (i.e. 1 line of your desired background) and change your css to:

```
.main {
  position: relative;
  background: url('../images/background.png') repeat-y top center; 
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I hope this helps

## OLD VERSION

Your `.main` has no height and `height:100%;` doesn't work because the elements containing it have no height themselves.

One possible solution would be to add this:

```
html, body, .main {
  height:100%;
}
```

This might be exactly what you need, but you may also run into other problems with this solution. It all depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Other possible solutions:

**Use viewport units**

```
.main {
  height:100vh;
}
```

Please be aware that some mobile devices interpret these differently from what you'd expect.

**Add the background to the body itself**

```
body {
  background: url('../images/background.png') no-repeat top center; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

As I wrote before: It's difficult to tell which solution is the best, it depends on your goal.

Comment: It appears from her comments that she wants the background image to determine the height, which I don't think is possible. i.e. not making her 5000px tall image fit in the browser widow but make the browser window 5000px tall.

Comment: @zgood Yep, that last comment made me think so too, unfortunately her answer to my question was less than enlightening. ;)

Comment: She would probably have to add the `<img>` in the DOM and remove it as a background image.

Comment: @humble.rumble yes but wouldn't the div with the background-image still need a height?

Comment: You're on the wrong track @humble.rumble `contain` will shrink the background-image, not expand the div. Judging by the fact that she just accepted my updated answer, I think I guessed her intention correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this style?

`html, body{ height: 100%;}`

Then adding a `height:100%;` to your `.main` div

Comment: If you want the image to determine the height then you can't use it as a `background`, you would have to add the image as a `<img />` tag

Answer (score 0):

You are working with background-image... Keep in mind that the size of the rendered image has nothing to do with the image it self, but with the element created to contain it.

Now, if you want your image to appear at 100% height and width you can use the property `background-size: contain`, instead of cover.
This will tell the browser that your image should not be cropped (as long as you have a height set for the .main element).

It seems to me, that the kind of effect you want is easier done if you just use the `<img>` tag instead of css background.

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue about flex box can`t fit the background height, and the code below suited for me. The rest background-size,repeat and position depends on yours.

```
html{
    height:auto;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```